# ActiveMQ JMS TCP Transport is incrementally changing port number on retries

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

After some JMS connectivity problems I've noticed in logs:

```
o.a.a.b.T.Transport:? - Transport Connection to: tcp://100.100.100.100:61141 failed: java.io.EOFException
o.a.a.b.T.Transport:? - Transport Connection to: tcp://100.100.100.100:61156 failed: java.io.EOFException
o.a.a.b.T.Transport:? - Transport Connection to: tcp://100.100.100.100:61148 failed: java.io.EOFException
o.a.a.b.T.Transport:? - Transport Connection to: tcp://100.100.100.100:61161 failed: java.io.EOFException
o.a.a.b.T.Transport:? - Transport Connection to: tcp://100.100.100.100:61192 failed: java.io.EOFException
o.a.a.b.T.Transport:? - Transport Connection to: tcp://100.100.100.100:61197 failed: java.io.EOFException
o.a.a.b.T.Transport:? - Transport Connection to: tcp://100.100.100.100:61226 failed: java.io.EOFException
o.a.a.b.T.Transport:? - Transport Connection to: tcp://100.100.100.100:61273 failed: java.io.EOFException
o.a.a.b.T.Transport:? - Transport Connection to: tcp://100.100.100.100:61241 failed: java.io.EOFException
```

Why JMS is retrying in such way? **Does ActiveMQ client/broker technology have any port discovery/negotation protocol?**

Comment: You'd need to provide a lot more information if you want someone to be able to answer this.

Comment: I'm just wondering if JMS at all have such feature

Comment: JMS is an API specification so no it doesn't have any such features.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ has [discovery](http://activemq.apache.org/discovery.html) using IP Multicast and [failover](http://activemq.apache.org/uri-protocols.html) mechanisms. Not clear why it reconnects to the same host, failover config may have the same host. Client configuration would be helpful to understand.